# Displaying data from doctrine in twig for loop

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, twig

Controller code:

```
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $books = $em->getRepository('Books\Model\Books')->findAll();

    return $this->render('Books/View/list.html.twig', array(
        'books' => $books
    ));
```

Twig template code:

```
{% extends 'Books/View/layout.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
<table>
   <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
   </tr>
   {% for row in books %}
       <tr>
           <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
           <td>{{ row.description }}</td>
       </tr>
   {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

I don't know why I don't see nothing in cell's designed for name and description. When I open developer console and look into html tree I see this cell's but empty..

Comment: When I open developer console and look into html tree I see this cell's but empty.. - I mean: I see 'td' tags but without data

Comment: I think the fact that you see tds implies that the query was successful and it is actually iterating over books. Are you sure the property names are correct? I would try dumping books to verify what's really there.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember You need to create getters:

```
class Books
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue */
    private $id;

    /** @Column(type="string") */
    private $name;

    /** @Column(type="string") */
    private $description;

    public function getName() { return $this->name; }
    public function getDescription() { return $this->description; }
}
```

Just read manual [7. Working with Objects](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html)

You might prefer to read markdown documentation [Doctrine1 Documentation](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine1-documentation). I am writing md files myself so prefer to read them too.